# Python: Convert List to String Items

Tags: python, sql, string, list, insert

I'm trying to insert data into SQL

This is a simple concept of the code:

```
# Establish Connection to SQL Database
connection = sqlite3.connect("MyDatabase.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Expenses VALUES DB_QMarks"

data = ['40', '50', '10']

# Execute SQL Query
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

When I execute this it returns an error:

**Expected: ("1", "2020-01-04", "40", "50", "10")**

**Actual Outcome: ("1", "2020-01-04", ['40','50','10'])**

**DB_QMarks** is code ran previously that creates a "(?)" for each object in the data list. The data variable is appended to from user input therefore there is no determinant of the length. I have code already that creates "(?)" for each object. This isn't the problem, the problem is removing the square brackets from the outcome of data so that it works correctly in the cursor.execute function.

The error returns "The current statement uses 5 bindings, there are only 3 supplied". How can I convert the list to the expected string with no brackets. I tried converting to a string but it replaces the brackets with double quotes (") and the same problem happens.

Thank you

Comment: This is not valid SQL: `INSERT INTO Table_Expenses VALUES (?)(?)(?)(?)(?)`. If you want to insert 1 record, with 5 columns, then: `INSERT INTO Table_Expenses VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Also what is `data` in `cursor.execute(sql, data)`? This variable should hold 5 values (one per question mark).

Comment: Hard to tell - you've left out how you get from assigning a list to `Expenses` to passing `data` as an argument.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the code on here.  The code is now accurate as to what it is in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql_output = ("1", "2020-01-04", ['40','50','10'])
# further processing into string as requested
string_output = ""
for x_val in sql_output:
    if type(x_val) == list:
        for val in x_val:
            string_output += "'" + str(val) + "' "
    else:
        string_output += "'" + str(x_val) + "' "
print(string_output)
```